# Plotting 20,000 points using High Charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to plot a dynamic graph that plots 10,000 to 20,000 points within a span of 1 second.On the x axis I have the time at a interval of 1 second,so the graph progresses showing the dynamic data constantly updating with new values and the time elapses in seconds in x axis time .How to do that ?I have searched enough but I did not get the desired answers.Using javascript.

Comment: Some code or live example would be nice. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

If your project is not must to use highcharts, for 10,000 to 20,000 points drawing per second, you can try to use other canvas based chart tool, like [processingjs](http://processingjs.org/). At this scale, canvas will be better on performance than SVG.